# Combining two different Queries out put in one XML

Tags: xml, t-sql

I need to produce a report that will be emailed so I am using XML format. I an currently producing the mail below and now have been asked to add a summary to the top. My SQL XML knowledge is lacking when it comes to combining the results of two queries into one XML. I can provide a script to create a input table if you need it. Thanks in advance.

Sample Data

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[temp_Matching_table2]
    
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_Matching_table2]
    (
        [Job_Num] [varchar](8) NULL,
        [Mail_Cat] [char](1) NULL,
        [Mail_Date] [date] NULL,
        [Mail_Class] [char](1) NULL,
        [TR_Scan_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[temp_Matching_table2] 
        ([Job_Num], [Mail_Cat], [Mail_Date], [Mail_Class], [TR_Scan_Date]) 
    VALUES 
        (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2021-12-27T09:41:19.000' AS DateTime)),
        (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CAST(N'2022-01-10T21:17:43.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1Q22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-11-12' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-18T15:24:56.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1Q22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-11-12' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-19T14:23:35.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1Q22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-11-12' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-28T13:05:44.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P102    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-21T00:16:48.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P102    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-21T05:57:11.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1A22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-18T08:10:03.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1A22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-23T15:21:15.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1A22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-23T22:09:33.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1A22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-24T06:57:16.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1A22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-24T07:12:44.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1A22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-29T03:00:31.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'O683    ', N'P', CAST(N'2021-11-12' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-14T18:17:29.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'O683    ', N'P', CAST(N'2021-11-12' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-15T12:36:38.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1B22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-06T16:54:18.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'1B22    ', N'T', CAST(N'2021-12-27' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-07T11:49:07.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'0107    ', N'C', CAST(N'2022-01-07' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-23T18:30:38.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'0107    ', N'C', CAST(N'2022-01-07' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-08T21:07:04.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'0107    ', N'C', CAST(N'2022-01-07' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-09T00:24:45.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'0107    ', N'C', CAST(N'2022-01-07' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-09T01:53:20.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'0107    ', N'C', CAST(N'2022-01-07' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-09T23:10:47.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'0107    ', N'C', CAST(N'2022-01-07' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-10T03:37:06.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'0107    ', N'C', CAST(N'2022-01-07' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-10T09:24:25.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P896    ', N'P', CAST(N'2022-01-28' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2021-12-31T08:29:40.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P896    ', N'P', CAST(N'2022-01-28' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-02T10:04:27.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P896    ', N'P', CAST(N'2022-01-28' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-03T13:53:18.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P896    ', N'P', CAST(N'2022-01-28' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-05T00:00:37.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P896    ', N'P', CAST(N'2022-01-28' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-05T00:58:14.000' AS DateTime)),
        ( N'P896    ', N'P', CAST(N'2022-01-28' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-07T05:54:35.000' AS DateTime)), 
        ( N'P896    ', N'P', CAST(N'2022-01-28' AS Date), N'3', CAST(N'2022-01-07T13:48:40.000' AS DateTime)); "

    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_UnMatching_Mail
    
SELECT * INTO dbo.temp_UnMatching_Mail FROM
    (
    SELECT 'PM' As RecType, Mail_Date,Job_Num,Mail_Cat,Mail_Class, COUNT(*) AS Total 
      FROM dbo.temp_Matching_table
     WHERE Job_Num IS NOT NULL 
       AND Mail_Date <= Cast(TR_Scan_Date AS Date)
     GROUP BY Mail_Date,Job_Num,Mail_Cat,Mail_Class
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'FM' As RecType, Mail_Date,Job_Num,Mail_Cat,Mail_Class, COUNT(*) AS Total 
      FROM dbo.temp_Matching_table
     WHERE Job_Num IS NOT NULL 
       AND Mail_Date > Cast(TR_Scan_Date AS Date)
     GROUP BY Mail_Date,Job_Num,Mail_Cat,Mail_Class
    ) a
 ORDER BY RecType, Mail_Date, Job_Num, Mail_Cat, Mail_Class

    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_NUM IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Not_Found] 
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mail_Date < Cast(TR_Scan_Date AS Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Past_Mail_Date]
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mail_Date >= Cast(TR_Scan_Date AS Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Future_Mail_Date]
          ,COUNT(*) AS Total 
    FROM dbo.temp_Matching_table
    for xml auto, elements, type, root('Summary')

    SELECT 
        oh.FileType, 
        P.Mail_Date, 
        P.Job_Num,
        P.Mail_Cat,
        P.Mail_Class,
        P.Total
    FROM [dbo].[Temp_UnMatching_Mail] P
    INNER JOIN  
            (       
            SELECT  RecType,
                    CASE RecType 
                    WHEN 'FM' THEN 'Future Mail    ' 
                    WHEN 'PM' THEN 'Past Mail      ' 
                    END AS FileType  
            FROM Temp_UnMatching_Mail
            GROUP BY RecType 
            ) oh
    ON p.RecType = oh.RecType
    for xml auto, elements, type, root('History')
```

[image: Current Email]

[image: Needed Email]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Does it have to be direct query output? Could this be an SSRS report?

Comment: Thank you and I know its hard to help when threes not information. At this point I am  unaware of how to upload everything you asked for and these comments are limited

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the answer to combining two different queries is to use a outside select.

Select
(Query1 results), (Query2 Results)

```
if  exists  (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [dbo].[temp_UnMatching_Mail]
            )
begin
    SELECT
    (
    SELECT oh.FileType
          ,s.Not_Found
          ,s.Past_Mail_Date
          ,s.Future_Mail_Date
          ,s.Total
     FROM
        (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_NUM IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Not_Found] 
               ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mail_Date < Cast(TR_Scan_Date AS Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Past_Mail_Date]
               ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mail_Date >= Cast(TR_Scan_Date AS Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Future_Mail_Date]
               ,COUNT(*) AS Total 
        FROM dbo.temp_Matching_table2 ) S
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 'Unmatch to Mailing Breakdown' AS FileType ) oh
    ON 1 = 1
    
    for xml auto, elements, type, root('Summary')
    ),

    (
    SELECT 
        oh.FileType, 
        P.Mail_Date, 
        P.Job_Num,
        P.Mail_Cat,
        P.Mail_Class,
        P.Total
    FROM [dbo].[temp_UnMatching_Mail] P
    INNER JOIN  
            (       
            SELECT  RecType,
                    CASE RecType 
                    WHEN 'FM' THEN 'Unmatched Future Mail Dates (Mailed Early?) ' 
                    WHEN 'PM' THEN 'Unmatched Past Mail Dates (Missing History?) ' 
                    END AS FileType  
            FROM temp_UnMatching_Mail
            GROUP BY RecType 
            ) oh
    ON p.RecType = oh.RecType
    for xml auto, elements, type, root('History')
    )
    for xml path('Stats') 
end

else    select cast('<NoRecords>No records available.</NoRecords>' as xml)
```